# Bundler compatible versions for gem "jekyll"

Tags: ruby, dependencies, jekyll, blogs

I'm trying to setup github page using Jekyll, currently it is using **minima theme**, and I want to change it to **jekyll-theme-hacker**.

So, I went to Gemfile, 
I added

```
gem "github-pages", group:jekyll_plugins
```

under the

```
gem "minima", "~>2.5"
```

And after saving it, I did

```
bundle install
```

But this gives me the error.

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "jekyll":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    jekyll (= 4.0.0)

  In Gemfile:
    jekyll (~> 4.0.0)

    jekyll-theme-hacker was resolved to 0.0.4, which depends on
      jekyll (~> 3.3)

Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using
only
the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.
```

I am very new to the Jekyll and Programming, I wonder why this happened.

As far as what I could figure out was, Bundler is a Gem management tool, which Gem stands for the library or module for ruby programming langauge. So what I was trying to do was trying to install all the necessary things for the my new theme.

However bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "jekyll". 
What does this exactly mean? Do I need a different dependency of jekyll to use my new theme? 
If it is so, How can I do it?

Thanks a lot in advance.

----EDIT----
This is how my **Gemfile.lock** looks like

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    addressable (2.7.0)
      public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 5.0)
    colorator (1.1.0)
    concurrent-ruby (1.1.5)
    em-websocket (0.5.1)
      eventmachine (>= 0.12.9)
      http_parser.rb (~> 0.6.0)
    eventmachine (1.2.7)
    ffi (1.11.1)
    forwardable-extended (2.6.0)
    http_parser.rb (0.6.0)
    i18n (1.7.0)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    jekyll (4.0.0)
      addressable (~> 2.4)
      colorator (~> 1.0)
      em-websocket (~> 0.5)
      i18n (>= 0.9.5, < 2)
      jekyll-sass-converter (~> 2.0)
      jekyll-watch (~> 2.0)
      kramdown (~> 2.1)
      kramdown-parser-gfm (~> 1.0)
      liquid (~> 4.0)
      mercenary (~> 0.3.3)
      pathutil (~> 0.9)
      rouge (~> 3.0)
      safe_yaml (~> 1.0)
      terminal-table (~> 1.8)
    jekyll-feed (0.12.1)
      jekyll (>= 3.7, < 5.0)
    jekyll-sass-converter (2.0.1)
      sassc (> 2.0.1, < 3.0)
    jekyll-seo-tag (2.6.1)
      jekyll (>= 3.3, < 5.0)
    jekyll-watch (2.2.1)
      listen (~> 3.0)
    kramdown (2.1.0)
    kramdown-parser-gfm (1.1.0)
      kramdown (~> 2.0)
    liquid (4.0.3)
    listen (3.2.0)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.10, >= 0.10.3)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.10)
    mercenary (0.3.6)
    minima (2.5.1)
      jekyll (>= 3.5, < 5.0)
      jekyll-feed (~> 0.9)
      jekyll-seo-tag (~> 2.1)
    pathutil (0.16.2)
      forwardable-extended (~> 2.6)
    public_suffix (4.0.1)
    rb-fsevent (0.10.3)
    rb-inotify (0.10.0)
      ffi (~> 1.0)
    rouge (3.11.1)
    safe_yaml (1.0.5)
    sassc (2.2.1)
      ffi (~> 1.9)
    terminal-table (1.8.0)
      unicode-display_width (~> 1.1, >= 1.1.1)
    thread_safe (0.3.6)
    tzinfo (1.2.5)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    tzinfo-data (1.2019.3)
      tzinfo (>= 1.0.0)
    unicode-display_width (1.6.0)
    wdm (0.1.1)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  jekyll (~> 4.0.0)
  jekyll-feed (~> 0.12)
  minima (~> 2.5)
  tzinfo (~> 1.2)
  tzinfo-data
  wdm (~> 0.1.1)

BUNDLED WITH
   2.0.2
```

Answer (score 10):

- Edit your **Gemfile** to look like this :

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'github-pages'
```

- Remove your **Gemfile.lock**
- Launch a `bundle` command.

That's it !
You're ready to deploy to github pages.

Comment: This worked for me, but I didn't need to edit my Gemfile to look like that..

Answer (score 1):

This is occurring because you are requesting conflicting versions of Jeykll. One option is to downgrade the version of Jeykll you are using by changing it in your `Gemfile`

```
-jekyll (~> 4.0.0)
+jekyll (~> 3.3)
```

and then running `bundle update jekyll`

If you wanted to run the latest version, you could fork the Gem, update the `jekyll` dependency version and test the changes. If it is working as expected you should submit a PR to the original repo and could use the fork while waiting for it to be merged.

Comment: In my Gemfile, it is defiend as `gem "jekyll", "~> 4.0.0"`. So I changed it to `gem "jekyll", "~> 3.3"` but it gives me an more error. It says, `Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "jekyll":
  In Gemfile:
    github-pages was resolved to 4, which depends on
      jekyll (= 1.1.2)`

Comment: And what do you mean by **fork the Gem**??? What is **PR** also?

Comment: Try running `bundle update` to see if that fixes it.

Forks are outlined here - https://help.github.com/en/github/getting-started-with-github/fork-a-repo

Pull-requests - https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/about-pull-requests

How to use a fork in your Gemfile https://bundler.io/v1.12/git.html

Comment: I ran into the same problem with "jekyll-theme-minimal".  I tried using `gem "jekyll", "~> 3.9"` and that worked.

Answer (score 1):

Version 3.7 worked for me, you could try and check the same.